# How can objdump emit intel syntax

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, objdump

How can I tell `objdump` to emit assembly in Intel Syntax rather than the default AT&T syntax?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

What you're looking for is `-M intel`. Use it as follows.

```
objdump -M intel -d program_name
```

Comment: On OS X, it turns out that /usr/bin/objdump may not actually be objdump at all, but actually llvm-objdump. You can use objdump --help, but it actually doesn't tell you about the option that gives you intel-style output, which appears to be `-x86-asm-syntax=intel` . Sigh.

Comment: Is there an easy way how to make `objdump` use the option `-M intel` as a **permanent default**?

Comment: @vitsoft Not really, it seems like `objdump` doesn't support passing "default" parameters via an environment variable or a `rc` file. The best way to go seems to be creating a function in your shell, like `objdump() { /usr/bin/objdump -M intel "$@" }` in Bash. This has its own set of issues, of course, for example I have no idea if `objdump` isn't going to complain about `-M intel` if you're not actually disassembling something.

Comment: @JohnClements as of https://reviews.llvm.org/rGe510860656bb81bd90ae3cf8bb5ef4dc8cd33c18 , llvm-objdump understands `-Mintel` like you'd expect. This will be in LLVM 13.

Answer (score 12):

If you want Intel mnemonic codes as well (instead of AT&T mnemonic codes), you can use:

`objdump -M intel intel-mnemonic -D <program's-object-file>`

Comment: Actually, `-M intel` already takes care of that. Try disassembling the  sequence `0f b7 c3` - with `-M intel` this will give you `movzx  eax,bx`, while without it objdump reverts to AT&T by default and you get `movzwl %bx,%eax`.

Comment: Oh right. I overlooked that completely in the interest of being more explicit. Thanks!

Comment: From reading the manual, `-M intel-mnemonic` _implies_ `intel`, not the other way around. I still don't know the differences between the two though. I did `objdump -M intel -d file > intel`, `objdump -M intel-mnemonic -d file > intel-mnemonic`, then `diff intel intel-mnemonic` and there were no differences. I even tried with `-D` instead of `-d` just in case there would be differences in the other sections.